# Calculate an expectation

Tags: probability-theory

suppose $X$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$.
what is $\mathbb{E}[\cos(X^3+5)]$ ?
I have tried this:
The CDF of $X$ is $$P(X\le x)=F(x)=\begin{cases}1-e^{-\lambda \cdot x} ,x\ge 0\\
 0,x\lt0 \end{cases} $$
Let $Y=\cos (X^3+5) $, then the CDF of  Y is:
$$P(Y\le y)=P(\cos (X^3+5)\le y )=P(X\le (\arccos(y)-5)^{\frac{1}{3}}) $$
Hence  $$P(Y\le y)=f((\arccos(y)-5)^{\frac{1}{3}})=1-e^{(\lambda \cdot \arccos(y)-5)^{\frac{1}{3}}} $$
Thus the PDF is :
$$f(y)=e^{\lambda \cdot \arccos(y)-5)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\cdot\lambda\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot (\arccos(y)-5)^{\frac{-2}{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} $$
Therefore, the expectation should calculate like this:
$$\mathbb{E}[\cos(X^3+5)]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{y\cdot f(y)\text dy}$$
And now I don't know how to deal with this huge staff.

Comment: Your $f(x)$ is wrong ! It should be $F(x)=(1-e^{-\lambda x})\boldsymbol 1_{x\geq 0},$ and thus $f(x)=e^{-\lambda x}\boldsymbol 1_{x\geq 0}$.

Comment: @Surb you forgot constant $\lambda$ in PDF.

Comment: @drhab : yes, thank you. So $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\boldsymbol 1_{x\geq 0}$.

Comment: @Surb yes , you are right . Edited just now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb E[g(X)]=\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)f_X(x)\mathrm d x.$$

Comment: Thank you for  the formula. I have calculated this integral. But I still don't know how to deal with the integral of cosine and exponential function. Could you show further skills?

Comment: @JaqenChou: It's (at my opinion) not possible to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

There is no need to calculate CDF and/or PDF of $Y=\cos(X^3+5)$.

You can find the expectation by calculating:$$\mathsf E\cos(X^3+5)=\int\cos(x^3+5)f_X(x)dx=\int_0^{\infty}\cos(x^3+5)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$

Comment: I have calculated it like this $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x^3+5) \cdot \lambda \cdot e^{-\lambda x} dx$ $=\int_{0}^{\infty} cos(x^3+5)\cdot (-e^{-\lambda x})'dx=-e^{-\lambda x}\cdot cos(x^3+5)|_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}(-sin(x^3+5)\cdot 3x^2dx=cos5+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}(-sin(x^3+5)\cdot 3x^2dx $.  But now I can't do more. Any further skills ?

Comment: Sorry, but I am really not good at this. Maybe you could try $\cos z=\frac12(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$ for $z=x^3+5$. No guarantee on succes, though. You could ask a new question about this with a link to this question.